# merge unallocated/free space sections

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

My system currently has Win11 + Ubuntu 22.04LTS installed, and they dual boot with no problem. They are both installed to the same SSD. I do have a 2nd SSD, but it is only for data storage.

I am trying to install Linux Mint Cinnamon now, and if I select **install alongside current operating systems** it seems to try installing the bootloader + OS partitions on the 2nd SSD, which I do not want - I would prefer to keep the current bootloader and just add Mint as the third entry on my 2TB disk, along Win11 and Ubuntu.

So I was going to follow these [instructions to install Mint without bootloader](https://averagelinuxuser.com/install-linux-mint-without-a-bootloader/) but figured I should try merging all the unallocated/free space sections on my OS disk first, but my research seems to indicate that it isn't really that simple.

I found this other AskUbuntu answer, [I want to merge an unallocated space with my Ubuntu Partition but i can't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361041/i-want-to-merge-an-unallocated-space-with-my-ubuntu-partition-but-i-cant), and I guess I kind of have an idea what to do from that post but am unsure. I saw this [Merge Unallocated partitions AskUbuntu Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197000/merge-unallocated-partitions) too, but I am still worried/don't really know if shifting things around like that might cause a boot problem.

Do I kind of need to merge and then un-merge partitions left-to-right to get all the unallocated space into one single section? Kind of like, increase the size of `/dev/nvme0n1p3` by the 468.45GiB in the unallocated space to the left and then decrease it back to the previous size, or something like that?

Thanks so so much!

[GParted/lsblk/Disks Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lllQG.jpg)

Comment: p3, p4, and p6 all look like Windows partitions. Use Windows tools to manipulate them. Moving partitions around is inherently risky, so backups are very wise.